# Upgrade terraform to specific version

Tags: homebrew, terraform

**Use case**

I have installed Terraform v0.11.13 via homebrew and as recommended by terraform I want to ugprade to version v0.11.14 before doing the major upgrade to v0.12.0.

**The problem**

When I run `brew upgrade terraform` or download the Mac package from the terraform website it would immediately update my terraform version to v0.12.0 I think.

**So how can I upgrade to v0.11.14 instead?**

Answer (score 416, accepted):

Especially when playing around with Terraform 0.12 betas, I learned to love [tfenv](https://github.com/tfutils/tfenv).

After installation (via `brew install tfenv` on MacOS), this allows you to easily discover, install and activate any Terraform version:

```
$ tfenv list-remote
0.12.0
0.12.0-rc1
0.12.0-beta2
0.12.0-beta1
0.12.0
0.11.14
...

$ tfenv install 0.11.14
[INFO] Installing Terraform v0.11.14
[INFO] Downloading release tarball from https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.11.14/terraform_0.11.14_darwin_amd64.zip
...
[INFO] Installation of terraform v0.11.14 successful
[INFO] Switching to v0.11.14
[INFO] Switching completed
```

If you want to switch to a different version:

```
$ tfenv use 0.12.0
[INFO] Switching to v0.12.0
[INFO] Switching completed
```

Comment: Stephen, you are the King!

Comment: Adding a `.terraform-version` file makes `tfenv` automatically switch to the right version for a given directory and it will even take care of auto-installing the correct version if not already installed.

Comment: I'me getting that: 'Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/google...

Error: Failed to query available provider packages'

Comment: if already a latest version is installed. You may need to unlink first `brew unlink terraform` before installing specific version from tfenv. Once installed, type `tfenv use 0.12.30` to use new version.

Answer (score 47):

For anyone looking to do the same without using homebrew:

1. Get source

```
$ wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.11.14/terraform_0.11.14_linux_amd64.zip

$ unzip terraform_0.11.14_linux_amd64.zip
```

2. Give binary executable permissions and install (will overwrite current version)

```
$ chmod +x terraform

$ sudo mv terraform /usr/local/bin/
```

3. Confirm version

```
$ terraform --version
```

Source: https://titosoft.github.io/kvm/terraform-and-kvm/#installing-terraform

Comment: i am getting this error mate with your code -bash: /usr/local/bin/terraform: cannot execute binary file

Comment: simple, straightforward.

Comment: This method is actually nicer than the accepted one as it avoids breaking terraform's simlink
Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 17):

There is a nice alternative to **tfenv** that I've been using for few years now - **[tfswitch](https://tfswitch.warrensbox.com/)**.

1. Simple installation process with:

```
# MacOS
brew install warrensbox/tap/tfswitch

# Linux
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/warrensbox/terraform-switcher/release/install.sh | bash
```

2. Supplies alpha, beta and release candidates terraform versions.
3. Supports multiple options for changing versions like:

- Manual with `tfswitch VERSION_NUMBER`.
- Automatically detects and switch to version described in `version.tf` file.
- Automatically switch to custom binaries under custom path (helpful for users or services with limited privileges).
- Automatically switch with `.tfswitchrc`, `.terrafom-version` - requires minimum setup and supports bash, zsh and fish.

4. Can be easily integrated with **Jenkins** and **CircleCI** - I haven't tested it out, these features were added 10 and 5 months ago respectively.

All in all it's a great and simple helper, would recommend this one.

Answer (score 7):

Apart from the conventional solutions, an easy implementation to the required problem would be installing **tfswitch**. It can change terraform versions with only one command. 
Installation and usage guide is provided in the given [link](https://warrensbox.github.io/terraform-switcher/).

***Note:***
You can not downgrade to previous versions after the script has been initialised (`terraform init`).

Answer (score 5):

Easy and best way to do:-

```
# MacOS
 brew install warrensbox/tap/tfswitch

# Linux
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/warrensbox/terraform- 
switcher/release/install.sh | bash
```

then use Either one of command to change version-

```
1. tfswitch ==> you will see option to select version.


2. tfswitch 0.14.3 ==> this way
```

Comment: ashishkarpe@Ashishs-MacBook-Air terraform %  brew install warrensbox/tap/tfswitch
==> Tapping warrensbox/tap
Cloning into '/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/warrensbox/homebrew-tap'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 549, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (107/107), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (106/106), done.
remote: Total 549 (delta 49), reused 5 (delta 1), pack-reused 442
Receiving objects: 100% (549/549), 69.88 KiB | 1.89 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (251/251), done.

Comment: Error: Invalid formula: /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/warrensbox/homebrew-tap/Formula/jscheck.rb
jscheck: Calling bottle :unneeded is disabled! There is no replacement.
Please report this issue to the warrensbox/tap tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
  /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/warrensbox/homebrew-tap/Formula/jscheck.rb:6

Comment: Error: Invalid formula: /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/warrensbox/homebrew-tap/Formula/hubapp.rb
hubapp: Calling bottle :unneeded is disabled! There is no replacement.
Please report this issue to the warrensbox/tap tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
  /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/warrensbox/homebrew-tap/Formula/hubapp.rb:9

Comment: Error: Invalid formula: /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/warrensbox/homebrew-tap/Formula/health-check.rb
health-check: Calling bottle :unneeded is disabled! There is no replacement.
Please report this issue to the warrensbox/tap tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
  /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/warrensbox/homebrew-tap/Formula/health-check.rb:9

Error: Cannot tap warrensbox/tap: invalid syntax in tap!

Answer (score 1):

I have used TF since 0.6 and actively use many different versions on my workstation. I do this with direnv [https://direnv.net/] since that was available for quite a while, and it works well for managing the TF binary version within a dir, plus it allows me to pass env vars per dir into TF with little hassle.

Sample .envrc:

```
export AWS_PROFILE=prod
export PATH=/usr/local/terraform/terraform-0.12.20:$PATH

export TF_VAR_dd_api_key=REDACTED
export TF_VAR_dd_app_key=REDACTED
```

When I cd into the dir containing this .envrc, not only does it put the correct TF binary in my PATH, it also sets my AWS profile and in this case some DataDog API keys.

When I want to upgrade TF, I ensure I have the desired binary placed into the correct location and edit the .envrc so it is in PATH. Ideally, the .envrc is not pushed to Github since other people could have different setups, and especially API keys should not go into the repo.

I know it's a little old fashioned but it works great for me.

Answer (score 1):

just use tfenv or tfswitch
both tools are really good.
good point is that if you have version requirements in terraform files when you do tfswitch it will automatically download and install version which you need.

https://tfswitch.warrensbox.com/

Answer (score 1):

I realised that I was using remote execution with terraform cloud instead of local execution, Thus, even though I upgraded my local terraform to 1.3.7, my remote version remain 1.1.7 therefore I had update the remote version by simply selecting the appropriate version from my workspace settings and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

below command will show all the available versions of terraform

**sudo apt policy terraform**

Install the desired version:

**sudo apt-get install terraform=1.4.4-1**

If you have a old version already, then uninstall it and run above commands

**sudo apt remove terraform**

Answer (score 0):

My two cents

There's a tool that works pretty much like `tfenv` but it also handles many other software

**mise-en-place**: https://mise.jdx.dev

You can manage versions for terraform terragrunt go java node python ruby .net  awscli postgres redis mongodb etc etc via plugins

Full list of plugins: https://github.com/mise-plugins/registry/blob/main/README.md

Hope you like it